# How do I set a picture as the background in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, background

I've added a jpg file to the App_localResources folder and in the document properites specified the photo in the Background propery.  In the designer it shows up as the background but when i run the page i still get the white page background.

Comment: What do you mean when you refer to the document properties and Background property. Are you talking HTML attributes? If I were you I would do it all via CSS.

Answer (score 5):

There's no distinctly ASP.Net way of doing this.

The canonical HTML way is to include this CSS:

```
body { background-image: url('background.jpg'); }
```

If you defined the body tag with `runat="server"` you could add the style inline using the Attributes property, but this wouldn't be a good idea. Layout details like this should go in the Stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that perhaps you have a stylesheet which might be overriding the background?

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the built in web server was still running and stop it, then re-run your application.  
* Right click on the tray icon and select "Stop".

The page is being cached, you should see your changes now.

Answer (score 0):

I used fiddler to trace the calls on the image. App_LocalResources\*.jpg return an 403 error. The App_LocalResources folder is really for use for localization.  If I move the image into an image folder it works fine.
Also rather than setting the Background property, use the Style property and the background property there.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to clear the cache of the browser after making changes to backgrounds and colors in order for it to apply when you run the site the next time.
Take a look here: 
    http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache